# Can anybody explain the output for a successful git push command ?? Especially the last line(master -->> master) ,

Tags: git

```
git push python_test_files master
Username for 'https://github.com': abhisekdas03590
Password for 'https://abhisekdas03590@github.com': 
Counting objects: 3, done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 261 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
To https://github.com/abhisekdas03590/python_test_files.git
 * [new branch]      master -> master
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- git push python_test_files master Username for 'https://github.com':
  xxxxxxxx Password for 'https://xxxxxxxx@github.com': **Pushing the code to repo on master branch with username and password**
- Counting objects: 3, done.**the number of loose objects for files committing to repo**
- Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 261 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done. **the number of loose objects for files writing to repo**
- Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0) To
  https://github.com/xxxxxxxx/python_test_files.git **Files are pushed to mentioned github repo**
- [new branch] master -> master**new branch is created in local is pushed to remote**

I hope this helps..! Happy coding..!

Comment: @abhisekdas035 Please accept the ans if that helps